# Any sample with WIF + WCF for login / password validation?

Tags: wcf, wif, usernametoken

There are many WIF examples for Asp.Net. However samples with WCFServiceLibrary are scarce.

Does anyone have an example with user credential of type username password?

I'd like to verify them via a CustomUserNameValidator which works on a view linked to my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using the WSTrustFeb2005 binding to create a channel between ADFS and a custom STS. For this I am using a custom security token handler with username/password validation. I've just blogged about this. Maybe you'll find it useful:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/09/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web_2465.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need WIF for that. Custom user name password validator [is feature of WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx). WIF is needed for advanced claim based and federated scenarios.

Comment: I agree with that. However I'd like to implement complex scenarios with WIF but at the moment I can't even get a simple user name password validation with WIF.

Comment: WIF doesn't use username/passwords. WIF is meant to deal with security tokens. How you obtain a valid security token is completely independent of how WIF validates and processes it in the app..